# pushing a viewcontroller from the right, dynamic navigation controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a UIView with a button on it, when the user clicks that button I have another xib file that I want to push. Now this view doesn't have a navigationcontroller so I create one dynamically like so :

```
   myVC *viewController = [[myVC alloc] init];
   UINavigationController *controller = [[UINavigationController alloc] 
           initWithRootViewController:viewController];
   [self presentModalViewController: controller animated: YES];
```

But this is modal, how can I have myV be pushed from the right?

Thanks.

Comment: Your current view `self` is inside a navigation controller? If not, why dont you add that inside navigation controller and push `myVC` on to that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this following format. This will help you.

```
 myVC *viewController = [[myVC alloc] initWithNibName:"myVC" bundle:nil];
 viewController.modalTransitionStyle=UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
 [[self navigationcontroller] presentModalViewController:viewController animated: YES];
```

This code is used to flip the new view controller horizondally.
Please refer "UIModalTransitionStyle".

Answer (score 0):

You need edit your appdelegate class and there itself you need to assign your view controller to navigation controller as a root class. Then it will automatically convert all yours view controller to navigation view. Try it out

Answer (score 0):

1. Initialize View controller
2. Intitilize UINavigationController root as 1st step view controller
3. present the nav

Here is the code

```
let vc = SomeViewController()

let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: con)

present(nav, animated: true, completion: nil)
```